# UIViewController ignore left/right slide movement

Tags: iiviewdeckcontroller

how can I ignore left or right slide movement in a UIViewController.
I am using [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/) and the center vc is a tabbarviewcontroller, there are two view controllers in that tabbarviewcontroller. In first vc of the tabbarvc, users can slide right to show the left vc but in the second vc, users can't do the same thing. so I want to ignore the slide movement in the second vc.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail. There is no "slide movements" on UIViewController without any other context.

Comment: By any chance are you looking for vertical-only scrolling in a UIScrollView?

Comment: @SanjitSaluja Hi,I am using [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/) and the center vc is a tabbarviewcontroller, there are two view controllers in that tabbarviewcontroller. In first vc of the tabbarvc, users can slide right to show the left vc but in the second vc, users can't do the same thing. so I want to ignore the slide movement in the second vc.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Using delegation and

```
_deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckNoPanning;
```

This works good!