# How can I disable the IIViewDeck functionality momentarily?

Tags: iiviewdeckcontroller

What it is: https://github.com/ViewDeck/ViewDeck

At certain times in my app I need to disable the menu slide-out functionality. I can't disable user interaction because then the main screen is unusable. How can I keep the menu from opening until I'm ready for the functionality to be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable** the menu's opening ability with

`_deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckNoPanning;`

and **re-enable** it with

`_deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckDelegatePanning;`

This helped: [UIViewController ignore left/right slide movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909199/uiviewcontroller-ignore-left-right-slide-movement)